# Java: Special Numbers with 2d Array

Tags: java, arrays

Here are some examples of what it would look like:

6 x 2:*

```
[1, 2]
[2, 3]
[3, 5]
[5, 8]
[8, 13]
```

3 x 4:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[4, 5, 7, 10]
```

4 x 3:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[3, 4, 6]
[6, 9, 13]
```

They are similar to Fibonacci numbers but in a rectangle.
Here are the rules:

1. The zeroth row contains all ones
2. Each subsequent row is filled according to these two rules: 1.The zeroth element of a row is the last element from the previous row. 2 Every subsequent element is the sum of the element to its left and the element to its left and up one row.

This is the printArray() to for my code (I know this is correct):

```
        for (int r = 0; r < arr.length; r++) {
            System.out.print("[");
            for (int c = 0; c < arr[0].length; c++) {
                System.out.print(arr[r][c] +
                                 (c < arr[0].length - 1 ? ", " : ""));
            }
            System.out.println("]");
        }
    }
```

The method nums() takes two integers, rows and cols, as its inputs and returns a rows × cols 2D array that contains specials Numbers.

```
public static int[][] kanekoNums(int rows, int cols) {
    // YOUR CODE HERE   
}
```

I think I would have to use nested loops for this. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, nested loops is the way to go:

```
public static int[][] kanekoNums(int rows, int cols) {
    int[][] arr = new int[rows][cols];
    // Initialize row 0
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        arr[0][c] = 1;
    // Walk down the array
    for (int r = 1; r < rows; r++) {
        arr[r][0] = arr[r - 1][cols - 1];
        for (int c = 1; c < cols; c++)
            arr[r][c] = arr[r][c - 1] + arr[r - 1][c - 1];
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Note that this includes the first row of all ones. If you want those to be chopped off:

```
static int[][] chop(int[][] arr) {
    int rows = arr.length - 1;
    int cols = arr[0].length;
    // Create an array that has 1 fewer row
    int[][] chopped = new int[rows][cols];
    // Copy the contents, shifting one row up
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        chopped[r] = arr[r + 1];
    return chopped;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to populate the first row with your first series of numbers. Looks like it's just using increments of 1 for that.

```
//Fill first row with starting numbers
for(int i = 0; i < numCols; i++)
  output[0][i] = i + 1;
```

Then you want to start your loop from the second row. Make sure to grab the last value from the previous row as the first value in the current row and then perform the grabbing and adding appropriately.

```
for(int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < numRows; rowIndex++) { //Skip first row since it already has values
  for(int colIndex = 0; colIndex < numCols; colIndex++) {
    if(colIndex == 0) {
      output[rowIndex][colIndex] = output[rowIndex - 1][numCols - 1]; //Grab last value from previous row for first value
      continue;
    }
    output[rowIndex][colIndex] = output[rowIndex][colIndex - 1] + output[rowIndex - 1][colIndex - 1]; //Sum previous value and previous value of row above
  }
}
```

Here's a full example:

```
public class KanekoNums
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    printArray(kanekoNums(6,2));
    printArray(kanekoNums(3,4));
    printArray(kanekoNums(4,3));
  }
  
  private static int[][] kanekoNums(int numRows, int numCols) {
    int[][] output = new int[numRows][numCols];
    
    //Fill first row with starting numbers
    for(int i = 0; i < numCols; i++)
      output[0][i] = i + 1;
    
    for(int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < numRows; rowIndex++) { //Skip first row since it already has values
      for(int colIndex = 0; colIndex < numCols; colIndex++) {
        if(colIndex == 0) {
          output[rowIndex][colIndex] = output[rowIndex - 1][numCols - 1]; //Grab last value from previous row for first value
          continue;
        }
        output[rowIndex][colIndex] = output[rowIndex][colIndex - 1] + output[rowIndex - 1][colIndex - 1]; //Sum previous value and previous value of row above
      }
    }
    
    return output;
  }
  
  private static void printArray(int[][] array) {
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      String row = "[";
      for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        row += array[i][j] + ", ";
      }
      row = row.substring(0, row.length() - 2) + "],";
      System.out.println(row);
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```